# GoogleMaps target doesn't get created in Pods project

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios9, xcode7, bitcode

System information: Xcode 7.0.1 w/ iOS 9

The issue i am having is: After adding the GoogleMaps pod (1.10.3) to my podfile, the application builds in Xcode for the iOS Simulator, but not for a device.

The error that occurring is as follows:

`ld: '/Users/<username>/Projects/Arsenal/LitterBug/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(GMSCachedTile.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Every post I have found mentions setting the `ENABLE_BITCODE` flag to 'No' for the pod target in the Pods project. That would be a viable option, if only to allow development to continue until Google updates the SDK, if the GoogleMaps target was being created in the Pods project.

My current podfile looks like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'AppName' do
    pod "Parse"
    pod "SwiftOverlays"
    pod "FBSDKCoreKit"
    pod "GoogleMaps"
    pod "FBSDKLoginKit"
    pod "FBSDKShareKit"

end

target 'AppNameTests' do
end
```

When i run `pod install --verbose` or `pod update --verbose`, the 'install targets' phase appears to NOT install the GoogleMaps target in the Pods project. This is indeed confirmed by viewing the project in the workspace.

There IS a target created along-side the other pod targets called 'Pods-appname'. I've tried disabling bitcode for this target, but it did not fix the issue.

If anyone else has experienced this issue, please let me know. The original error i received is currently being tracked as an issue and can be viewed here:  [GoogleMaps issue 8219](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8219)

The current workaround requires a GoogleMaps target existing in the Pods project in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by Setup **Enable Bitcode = NO** in Build Settings.

**Project>Build Settings>All>Build Options>Enable Bitcode = NO**

**[image: Project>Build Settings>All>Build Options>Enable Bitcode = NO]**

Answer (score 0):

Just select `Pods` in `PROJECT` and set `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `YES`.
[image]